Why does my Lambda hang when attempting to copy more than 21 files in S3?
It works fine with up to 21 files, takes a couple of seconds. But if I try feeding it more than 21, it hangs indefinitely and times out (> 30 seconds). From what I saw online, I am very far from hitting the S3 concurrent requests limit (which should be in the thousands), so I'm really not sure what could be happening.
Here's the relevant part of the code, It specifically hangs on the await s3_client.copy line:
async def _copy_image(
    s3_client, source_key: str, destination_key: str, bucket_name: str
) -> None:
    copy_source = {
        "Bucket": bucket_name,
        "Key": source_key,
    }

    await s3_client.copy(
        CopySource=copy_source,
        Bucket=bucket_name,
        Key=destination_key,
    )


async def copy_images_for_new_guide(
    keys: list[str],
    new_guide_id: int,
    org_id: int,
) -> None:
    session = aioboto3.Session()

    async with session.client(
        "s3",
        region_name=variables.secrets.AWS_REGION_NAME,
    ) as s3_client:
        tasks = []
        for key in keys:
            new_key = (
                f"orgs/org_{org_id}/guide_{new_guide_id}/{key.split('/')[-1]}"
            )
            tasks.append(
                _copy_image(
                    s3_client, key, new_key, variables.settings.IMAGES_BUCKET
                )
            )

        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

What could be causing this behavior?

You might also investigate aiboto3 to see if it suffers the same problem.

@jarmod it was indeed an aioboto3 problem, thanks

The issue was with aioboto3 and it's default connection pool limit. I set it to 100 like this:
s3_config = Config(max_pool_connections=100)

    async with session.client(
        "s3",
        region_name=variables.secrets.AWS_REGION_NAME,
        config=s3_config,
    ) as s3_client:

And now everything works fine.
